# webpack - bundle css from third-party module

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I have a project made with create-react-app, I didn't change the default webpack configuration. I'm using a third-party component, which imports several CSS files internally.

(in my component)

```
import OwlCarousel from 'react-owl-carousel';
```

(inside react-owl-carousel)

```
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css";
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css";
```

I also import my custom styles to override defaults 
(also in my component, below third-party component import)

```
import '../styles/pages/home.css';
```

it all works fine in development mode, both CSS files are included in separate `<style>` tags. However, when I build a production bundle, `dist` files are not added there, they are still loaded as `<style>` tags, while my CSS file is bundled along with the rest of project CSS files. Main CSS bundle is loaded before `<style>`s, making the override useless. 
When I import the same styles directly from my component, they are bundled just fine, but the problem is still there, because they're loaded once again from the third-party component.

Is it possible to bundle the styles from the component? They are hardcoded there, I can't remove their import. If it's not going to work, can I at least change the tags order, making the CSS bundle last, after the `<style>` tags?